# Sudo can't resolve hostname

Tags: virtualbox, debian, dns, proxy, sudo

```
$ curl http://google.de  # DNS resolution works fine
...
$ sudo curl http://google.de
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'google.de'

$ echo $http_proxy
http://proxy:8080

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1   debian
# ip6-stuff below

$ hostname
debian
```

I am using Debian squeeze (LXDE) inside VirtualBox and can do admin stuff via a real root console or via `su root`. I added my user to the sudoers group and can do stuff like editing via sudo, e.g., `sudo vim /etc/hosts`. I'd like to use `sudo` instead of `su root`.

Why are `curl` (and other tools like `aptitude`) not able to resolve the hostnames, but when using them as normal user or plain root everything works fine?

**Edit:** Here is the solution (Thx to Paul):

```
$ sudo visudo
# add this line
Defaults        env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"
# above this line
Defaults        env_reset
```

Comment: I would first try either setting http_variable in root's environment or using curl's -x option to use proxy while using sudo. `-x, --proxy <[protocol://][user@password]proxyhost[:port]>`

Comment: I added the `http_*` var in `/etc/bash.bashrc`, but Pauls solution also worked. Do I also have to set such var in `/etc/environment`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are running sudo, you are running a new shell as root, in which the command is executed.  Only the environment variables in the /etc/sudoers file are copied into the new shell.

To get around this for one command you can do

```
sudo env http_proxy=$http_proxy curl http://google.de
```

Or you can edit /etc/sudoers (use visudo!) and add

```
Defaults     env_keep = http_proxy
```

This will pass the variable through automatically.

Comment: I changed the settings via visudo (<-- nice!!) and added `Defaults env_keep = "http_proxy https_proxy ftp_proxy"` above `Defaults env_reset`. Thx, this works fine now